Instrumentation Amp Error Budget... now what?
Bit of a pre-amble before going into the question. I'm working on a project to try and get 100mg worth of resolution out of a 5kg load cell, and I am trying to figure out if my current approach is a fool's errand.
The load cell in question has an excitation voltage of 5V and a full-scale output of 15mV with an output impedance of ~300Ω. By my calculation, 100mg would be 0.002% of the full load or 20ppm. This means I need to measure a stable voltage of at least 300nV
I'm amplifying the loadcell with an AD8422 Instrumentation Amplifier with a Gain of 100 using an external 5ppm resistor. I've used the Instrumentation Amplifier Diamond Plot Tool to verify that I'm within the device's operating range and could/should increase my gain.
I've gone through the datasheet and calculated the various errors with RTI according to AN593, shown below. I have done some basic testing and found the PCB (circuit) temperature stays pretty constant, so I'm using a small delta T of 0.3C for my estimates.
My understanding of the ppm value with RTI tells me that I should budget for that much ppm's worth of error with respect to the full-scale voltage.
So, I should budget for approximately.

407uV of Accuracy error
616nV of drift error over 0.3C
300nV of noise error

I don't think the accuracy or noise errors worry me, I think I know how to compensate for that. The drift error does concern me. If I'm correct with my understanding, without some sort of temperature compensation, my drift error will exceed my resolution by double with less than half a degree of temperature fluctuation.
Does my interpretation sound correct, and this approach is a waste of time, or do I have a fundamental misunderstanding of the math, and maybe there's hope?
[Edit] I'm wondering if I need to think about this in terms of RTO instead of RTI. I'll have to double check this but the effects of some error values are reduced by increasing the gain. I understand there will be other trade off, there is no free lunch.




AD8422ARZ








Absolute Accuracy







Input Offset Voltage
60
uV

4000.0
ppm


Output Offset Voltage
300
uV

20000.0
ppm


Input Offset Current
0.3
nA

6.6
ppm


Common Mode Rejection
126
dB

83.5
ppm


Gain
0.2
%

2000.0
ppm


Resistor
1.00
%

1000.0
ppm





Total
27190.1
ppm


















Drift from 25 to
25.3






Gain Drift
80
ppm

24.0
ppm


Resistor Drift
5
ppm

1.5
ppm


Input Offset Voltage
0.4
uV/C

8.0
ppm


Input Offset Current
1
nA/C

6.6
ppm


Output Offset Voltage
5
uV/C

1.0
ppm





total
41.1











Resolution







Gain Non Linearity
10
ppm of FS

10.0
ppm


Typ 0.1 Hz–10 Hz Voltage Noise, uV p-p
0.15
uV/pp

10.0
ppm





Total
20.0
ppm





















Grand Total
27251.2
ppm




What load does your full scale voltage correspond to??

ooooops.  left out the m

Full-scale voltage translates to 5kg

Something another engineer brought up with me is that the Input offset voltage drift is probably a big killer. At 0.4uV/C my input is likely to drift outside my 0.3uV resolution with 1C of thermal fluctuation.
